# Broken dependencies

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, apt

I deleted contents of /opt , and now, **spotify and google chrome** won't work because I deleted their dirs. If I try to remove them, fix them, upgrade them or anything, I get this:

```
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
enter code heredpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--remove):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error status 1
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
```

A part of this is translated, but only a small part.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this on my machine by deleting my /opt folder and then reviving google-chrome. So i know it works. Kindly follow the following steps in order to revive your google-chrome:

1. [Download the google chrome **debian** file](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) from this link according to your OS.
2. After downloading it open a terminal windows in the location of the debian file and run the following command to **re-install** google-chrome

   sudo dpkg -i yourgooglechromedebianfile.deb
3. Your google-chrome is up and running again. :)

Comment: But with Spotify, they only suggests to add their repo, and install package. But no .deb to download

Comment: OK, in /var/cache/apt/archives apt stores those .deb files. But: Reinstalling spotify this way won't work